# How do I install khttpd and run it and view its source code?

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

I want to get started with khttpd but am unable to find much useful information on line.

How do I verify khttpd is installed on my ubuntu machine? How do I install it if it isn't? How do I run it? How do I verify it's running? How do I download/view the relevant source code?

thanks in advance for any answers.

EDIT:

The official website for khttpd is http://www.fenrus.demon.nl/

What I've found so far is that khttpd is a kernel module that must be configured and inserted into the kernel. What is lacking is instructions of how to do that on Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no such package in the [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=khttpd) [repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=khttpd). Could you please be more specific? What is upstream URL for *khttpd*?

Comment: @N0rbert I've edited my question with the requested information.

Comment: 20 years passed, it seems to be obsolete as they talk about 2.x kernels. About the source code - they provide patches ([example](http://www.fenrus.demon.nl/persistent.diff)) for very old kernels. And then it was last seen in [2.5.24](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.5/ChangeLog-2.5.24).

Comment: @N0rbert As of kernel 2.3.14, kHTTPd is integrated into the kernel. So I'm guessing we need to look in the kernel source for updated sources.

Comment: The clue from 2.4 is [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/wtarreau/linux-2.4.git/tree/net/khttpd/README?id=85dc1ddb804fe04e0bbb8695a4618b9997d17f6d). The corresponding config key [was](http://linux-sxs.org/upgrading/config243/24net4.html) [`CONFIG_KHTTPD`](https://osdn.net/projects/linux-kernel-docs/scm/git/linux-2.4.36/blobs/master/Documentation/Configure.help). Some repositories on GitHub have [mentions](https://github.com/search?q=%22CONFIG_KHTTPD%22&type=code) of it.